# Design Document of Text2Onto

Tags: ontology

Does anybody know if there is any design document of Text2Onto? I am trying to study its source code. It would be very helpful if there is any documentation about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there isnt much on Text2Onto. Not exactly a design doc but here are a few links you can refer to

- [Algorithms for Classifying Concepts in Text2Onto](http://ryadyo.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/algorithms-for-classifying-concepts-in-text2onto/)
- [Concept and Instance Extraction Algorithms in Text2Onto](http://ryadyo.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/concept-and-instance-extraction-algorithms-in-text2onto/)
- [SubcatRelationExtraction Algorithm](http://ryadyo.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/subcatrelationextraction-algorithm/)